# Excel VBA to insert missing columns based from a list?

Tags: excel, vba

So I'm very new to excel VBA so I'm hoping anyone can assist.

I have an array with a list of column headers:

Array = ("FName", "LName", "Email", "Country", "Gender")

And then I have an excel sheet which already contains columns with headers. I want to compare my array with the headers in the excel sheet and for any missing header it will insert a new column.

So for example, if the sheet only has these columns:

FName | LName | Gender

Then after running the sub, it will insert new columns that were missing:

FName | LName | Gender | Email | Country

Any help on how I can perform this with a macro?

Thank you so much for any assistance that you can provide.

Comment: I would start by using the search bar at the top and typing in: VBA add columns.  Then try something and when you get stuck, then come back here and post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work - note that it checks for the case to match.  It also doesn't know if the columns are out of order, simply adds in a missing one.

```
Sub t()
Dim headers() As Variant
headers = Array("FName", "LName", "Email", "Country", "Gender")

Dim i As Long
For i = LBound(headers) To UBound(headers)
    If Cells(1, i + 1).Value <> headers(i) Then
        Columns(i + 1).EntireColumn.Insert
        Cells(1, i + 1).Value = headers(i)
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```